# How can I choose the right stabilizer for a 3-phase 415 V supply system?

Tags: power-supply, motor, three-phase, induction-motor, stabilizer

[image]I have a question about how to select the right capacity of voltage stabilizer for a 3-phase supply system.

That system has the following type of load and capacity:

1. Two 1 hp 3-phase motor, 440 VAC (M1 and M2), 1.7 A.
2. 4 kW resistive heater (2 heaters on one phase (H1 & H2), other 2 heater are on (H3 & H4) other 2 phases).

As per my calculations, 7 kVA is sufficient with an 0.8 power factor. Could someone verify this? Please consider the inrush current of the motors too.

Comment: A diagram would be appropriate

Comment: @VoltageSpike added sir. Pls check.

Comment: Diagram legend reads 415 V Motor, prose states 440 V - just saying. Line voltage for 230 V star voltage is 400 V, anyway.

Comment: There's pretty little to base consideration of "inrush" current on - that's load dependant. `As per my calculations, 7 kVA…` Please put those in the question body, too. (Even without spin-up/inrush, there's a significantly higher value on the back of my envelope, assuming rated kVA relates directly to rated current per phase.)

Comment: @greybeard how to calculate it with inrush?

Comment: (`how to calculate [current needed] with inrush?` search, including electronics.stackexchange.com. If not satisfied with results, ask a separate question.)